# Asymmetric Encryption

Tags: polkadot-js

We are building a substrate blockchain backed by polkadot js. While working on a task I have a requirement of public/private key encryption and decryption. for ex:

**Sender's Actions:**

The sender obtains the recipient's public key, which is publicly available. The sender uses the recipient's public key to encrypt the message. The sender then sends the encrypted message to the recipient.

**Recipient's Actions:**

The recipient, who possesses the corresponding private key, uses it to decrypt the message. After decryption, the recipient can read the original message.

I cannot find any method to encrypt and decrypt using public/private keys in the Polkadot-js library. We are eager to explore how this can be achieved and would greatly appreciate your valuable feedback and guidance on implementing asymmetric encryption in our chat application.

Answer (score 0):

Polkadot.js allows to encrypt and decrypt messages using the NaCl library. More info in [this doc page](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/util-crypto/examples/encrypt-decrypt).